# Issues with enumerating PSObject Collections in CSHTML but not CS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, collections, psobject

I'm writing a small web app that requires I display the properties of a collection of PSObject on an ASP.NET C# Web Page.

In my controller class, a .cs file, I can access the First() method of a collection as such:

```
Collection<PSObject> test = new Collection<PSObject>();
test.First();
```

However when I try and do something similar in my .cshtml, trying to enumerate the property names for the table header, I get an exception that this method does not exist.

```
<tr>
        @{
            if (ViewBag.VIDatastores != null)
            {
                foreach (var prop in ViewBag.VIDatastores.First().Properties)
                {
                    <th>@prop.Name</th>
                }
            }
        }
</tr>
```

Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection' does not contain a definition for 'First'

I have also tried simply accessing element 0, as there is a null-check already in place:

```
foreach (var prop in ViewBag.VIDatastores[0].Properties)
```

Which returns a different exception:

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Now I of course debugged this, and the Properties property correctly enumerates in the Locals window (it is most absolutely not null).

What a I doing wrong?

The closest matching answer seemed to point to a missing assembly reference in web.config; but since this class is in System.dll (to my knowledge) and it is already referenced properly, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I'd highly recommend [using view models](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/accessing-your-models-data-from-a-controller) instead of the ViewBag (After all the M in MVC stands for model).

Comment: I'd love to, but AFAIK there is no way to use a PowerShell data-source in Entity Framework without a $700 paid library, and I dont know how to write my own Model that encapsulates it (yet).

Comment: What you just said makes no sense.  If you can populate a ViewBag you can populate a model.

Comment: Ok then, maybe i'm over-complicating something in my grey-matter. Time for more googling. Thanks